# Please avoid lengthening existing duplicate chains

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions

A recent example:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/433029/finding-my-ip-without-using-google
is tagged as a duplicate of
[Command to know my external IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392207/command-to-know-my-external-ip-address)
which is itself a duplicate of [How can I find my public IP using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145012/how-can-i-find-my-public-ip-using-the-terminal)
which is a duplicate of [Command for determining my public IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)

Apart from the suggestion that merging something here might not be a bad idea™ it would already help if reviewers took the time to track the "original".

Comment: I fixed the string problem.

Comment: Remember that there are some questions that is "how do I do X **using the command line**" are not duplicates of "how do I do X" since the later can have GUI methods

Comment: @Braiam true - still I would want reviewers not to point to a question which in itself is marked as duplicate.

Comment: I noted this in chat the other day when I was in the close-queue and saw that more than one close-vote was directed at something that was already on hold.  I went the one extra click and dropped a line in chat.  Maybe this should be tagged PSA and pinned in chat or something...

Comment: Keyword "minecraft" can use some de-duplication too.

Comment: @minerz029 thx for correcting my Austringlish :-)

Comment: Sometimes these chains may occur **through no fault or wrongdoing of the people doing it and are essentially unavoidable**.  For example, C is marked duplicate of B first, *then* B is later marked duplicate of A.  The person who linked C to B did not do anything wrong as no chain existed, and the person who linked B to A had no way of knowing that B was already the target of some other duplicate.  Just wanted to point out that we should not necessarily blame anybody when these chains occur.  But we should try and fix them when we notice they've occurred.

Comment: @neon_overload actually they do... well, they can infer going by the "Linked" section at the right.

Comment: Should someone write a script to find dupe chains, so they can be found and eliminated from the dumps?

Comment: I'll be making those a circular reference in a few minutes so that the last one is a duplicate of the first one...  Will it blow up just AU or the entire SE network???  **;-)**